# How do I update my collection view inside of a loop?

Tags: arrays, swift, loops, uicollectionview

I am trying to run a loop, but after the loop finishes each time I want to update my collection view. I can't quite figure out how to make it update during the loop, it only updates after the loops finishes. Any help would be much appreciated! Here is the code I'm using:

```
    var pM = possibleMoves(x: gS)
    while pM.isEmpty == false {
        let t = simBestMove(x: gS, y: score, tests: gamesToSim)
        gS = t.gS
        gS = newTile(q: gS)
        score = t.score
        boardCollectionView.reloadData()
        scoreLabel.text = String(score)
        print(score)
        pM = possibleMoves(x: gS)

    }
```

Comment: What do you want to update in the collectionView? And what is the need to reload the collectionView in every iteration? Why don't you update the dataSource in the loop and reload the collectionView only once?

Comment: The collection view is a four by four square with 16 numbers. I want to update it to see the games progress as it is simulating. I'm sorta new to this, what do you mean update the dataSource in the loop?